# Should I answer the OP or to the community?

Tags: discussion

I just saw that [my accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23263324/where-should-i-use-rel-nofollow/23263466#23263466) got downvoted, without a comment.

This has got me thinking, if I should answer the OP or people on Stack Overflow.

It is evident that the OP has found his answer to his question in my answer, which is why he accepted my answer.

So, should I answer keeping the OP in mind or "what others would think"?

Comment: SO has a bigger mission than solving the specific problem of this individual asker. Sure, the OP got an answer, but at what expense? The question is off topic, but now the OP (and perhaps other new users) thinks that this is a good place to get answers to such questions. They will post more bad questions in the future, and the cycle continues. If you let downvote and close bad questions (instead of answering them) you help to promote good behavior and discourage bad.

Comment: FWIW I don't think you fully answered the OPs question (the one he wrote, which may not have been the one in his head), which I imagine is the same opinion the downvoter had. That or he just thought the other answer was better, and wanted to rank the answers as such by -1ing you and +1ing the other.

Answer (score 4):

I've noticed that when a topic gets flagged as off topic a lot of time people will downvote as many things as they can. I don't know that this is the right way to handle it, but I think that's the problem.

That said, I think it's a good idea to do what you can to answer the OP but make your answer as applicable to the community as possible.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274919/downvoting-good-answers-on-bad-questions-helpful-or-not