# Downvoting good answers on bad questions, helpful or not?

Tags: discussion

What's the community consensus on this?  It seems to be a fairly recent behaviour on SO.  Is it helpful for the community and long term quality control on Stack Overflow?

On the one hand we have reversal badge (*Provided answer of +20 score to a question of -5 score*).  Badges generally seem to be designed to encourage the kind of behaviour desired.

On the other hand, the fact that people are doing it is a signal from the community.  And I think I understand the message ("don't pick up trash"?), but I'm not sure about that part.