# I was able to answer a low quality question and got downvoted

Tags: discussion, answers, downvotes, question-quality

I answered a vague, poorly done question where OP did no research.

He wanted to send data from one page to another. And I gave some very basic code using which you can acheive it with GET.

But what happened is that I got a couple of downvotes on the basis (at least I think so) of `poor security`

Link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27057891/4088472

Is this common behavior? Is it policy? Or was it actually my fault.

Comment: *"I answered a vague, poorly done question where OP did no research"* ... don't do that. Don't encourage them. And yes, poor security practices would be a fair enough reason to downvote you.

Comment: Ok then, maybe it was not exactly a good idea to answer... but did it really deserve downvotes?

Comment: I'd say it's fair enough, yes.

Comment: related (not a duplicate): [Downvoting good answers on bad questions, helpful or not?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274919/839601)

Comment: Except that it wasn't a good answer @gnat

Comment: @Bart that's why I explicitly mentioned "not a duplicate"

Comment: Me no read good @gnat. Me apologize.

Comment: The PHP tag gets lots of shitty questions (no wonder, seeing the language *badum pssst*). That community works hard to keep them to a minimum (see [cv-pls]). You encourage bad behavior, you're going to bring their wrath down upon you. But do what you want. Poke that bear.

Comment: @will No bear poking - Got it!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You have given an answer, that though is a solution to the question, if used is *actively harmful*, in that it opens up the OP to security problems.

As such, it was downvoted. That's absolutely right and fair.

If I see an answer promoting bad practices, I will downvote it. So should you.

Comment: So when I give code, there must not be any obvious security issues?

Comment: @ViruZX consider this, if you were looking for help, would you want someone to give you a solution that was obviously a security risk?

Comment: You should provide quality answers. That gets you upvotes. Answers with obvious security issues aren't quality answers.

Comment: @ViruZX - there shouldn't be non-obvious ones either... We expect answers to be of high quality - that **includes** not giving bad advice or code that has vulnerabilities. It includes code that can actually compile and works, for example.

Comment: Except the logical conclusion to this practice is that you should downvote a question that uses a coding style you don't agree with...

Comment: @Clara, coding style does not have much to do with good security practices.

Comment: @ClaraOnager - actively harmful != I don't like this style.

Comment: Also, answering obviously bad questions is actively harmful to the site as a whole and is a downvote reason per se.

Comment: I know all of that I'm just saying that downvotes need to be used sparingly as it reminded me of a comment (and possible downvote) I received recently regarding a coding style point that another user disagreed with

Comment: @ClaraOnager If someone wants to downvote solely because they don't like the style of an answer, they can, and there is no recourse against it. This being said, I'd bet that most of us don't think that a disagreement is style is a *sufficient* reason to downvote.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that your answer contains a syntax error certainly isn't helping.