# Is it a good idea to answer low quality posts?

Tags: discussion

I'm not really asking it to myself. I'm trying to make some reasonable answers for the other people who would want to answer this kind of question.

There are many low quality posts around which potentially will get many down votes. I see people answer those questions willing to get reputations or simply just trying to help the guy.

My question is: *Is it a good idea to answer to the low quality posts?*

Doesn't it make them ask more low quality questions and make Stack Overflow full of this kind of question?

In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35264972/array-values-getting-overwritten-c-sharp) (*if it's not deleted yet*) I told someone that *answering a low quality question is a bad idea. (Or at least is NOT a good idea)*.

He asked why? And someone else had a good answer for it.

> Answering bad questions makes the OP believe it is acceptable to ask
>   this kind of question, having that answer upvoted means that this
>   question will not get automatically deleted any more.

Comment: Wouldn't answering them encourage even more low quality posts?

Comment: Questions with low quality are usually 
1. offtopic
or 2. unclear. So you either should not answer or cannot answer

Comment: Ask yourself: Would I close this? If your answer is yes, you shouldn't answer.

Comment: **Ironically** my question itself is becoming a sample of a *low quality* question!

Comment: see also: [Downvoting good answers on bad questions, helpful or not?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274919/downvoting-good-answers-on-bad-questions-helpful-or-not)

Comment: SO is awash in crap questions like this.  There is no decent way to stop the flood, the company refuses to provide tools to make it easy to get rid of them and the community is beyond able to handle it by a factor of ~two.  SO users are cracking down on people that answer these kind of questions, fueled in no small part by recent meta posts about it.  Whether that *actually* does anything to discourage neophytes from adding crap is a theory that is not backed-up by any proof as yet.  The word "reputation" is close in the dictionary to "reputable", not the same thing here.

Comment: Note that closure as a *duplicate* does not mean that your question is low-quality. There is a big difference. If a high quality post is a duplicate, it still gets closed as a duplicate. So your question here is not necessarily low quality. You should easily be able to tell the difference, as Hans says, we are literally awash in crap questions on the main site.

Comment: My new argument against answering bad questions, since folks answering them claim they help the OP, is this: Let's say the OP gets a question ban and the question continues to get down votes. They *could* have deleted the question to stop the score from getting worse (even though the existing votes would still count), except this question has an answer on it. By answering a potentially unsalvageable question, you make it that much harder to escape a ban because the OP can't prevent the question from getting more down votes.

Comment: @HansPassant FWIW they recently [tested stronger tools to stop the flood](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7723/31260 "'The number of votes required to close and reopen questions is temporarily reduced . . . for science!'") at Programmers - and were scared by [results of this experiment](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7797/31260 "'The increase in closure rate makes reducing the number of votes required to close questions impractical...'")

Comment: Hmya, they made it easier to close questions and the close rate went up, badaboom.   Projecting their conclusion: the worst possible thing that could happen at SO is having more active users to help out in moderating the flood.  Lovely.  No wonder we are having this structural problem.

Comment: Even Jon's own analysis indicates to me that the problem is still fundamental disagreement about what the scope of Programmers is, @gnat. I don't claim to know about the culture on sites I don't participate on, but I don't think that's a problem with Stack Overflow. The scope is pretty clearly defined, and there are a whole lot of bad questions that are just painfully obvious. More to the point, I can't imagine what is wrong with having more questions closed. What is "scary" about that?

Comment: @CodyGray Jon's (and your) understanding is about two years outdated, Programmers scope is set about as firmly as that of SO. As for what scared them, refer the "Summary" section in [the post about results of the experiment](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7797/31260)

Comment: You're really asking "Is it a good idea to **encourage** low quality posts?"