# How wrong is it to answer "bad" questions?

Tags: discussion

[This question is a spinoff of [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/372945/), but doesn't really have anything to do with it..]

At a well-intentioned answer to a [now-deleted post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51980923/), someone commented:

> please don't spend your time answering poor questions like this - as this question is very likely to be put on hold, closed, and deleted, your time will have been wasted...

As someone who regularly answers "bad" questions, I have to say I am always offended by comments like these. Why would you discourage me from trying to reach out and help someone?  Why would you say it's a waste of time to *answer that person's question?*

I do understand that it is not SO's primary purpose to help people.  I do understand that it is SO's primary purpose to build a repository of high-quality answers to high-quality questions.  But I hope we can agree that helping people is at least a secondary purpose of SO.  So if someone asks a question which seems interesting and non-horrible to me, oftentimes I'm motivated to answer it, even if it's been downvoted, even if in the eyes of others it's horrible, even if it's nominally a duplicate.

One reason is that when a person legitimately (in the opinion of an answerer like me) deserves help, often they deserve *individualized* help.  Often, asking them to go to an allegedly identical (but sometimes rather tenuously connected) "duplicate" post, and try to glean the answer to their particular question, is tantamount to asking them to have found their answer on the open internet -- which they obviously weren't able to do, otherwise they wouldn't be asking here.

So I would never discourage anyone from leaving a good answer to a "bad" question.

(Here's an example of what I'm talking about.  If you're learning C, it's just about guaranteed that at some point you will become confused about the `++` operator.  It's quite likely that in an attempt to understand the precise behavior of the `++` operator, you will write code like `printf("%d %d\n", i++, ++i)`.  And even though you thought you understood `++`, the output of this program will make no sense.  So you're likely to ask, "Why didn't I get the result I expected?" or "What's the correct result?".  But if you ask either of these questions on SO, in less than a minute it will be closed as a duplicate of [Why are these constructs (using `++`) undefined behavior in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/).  But that's actually a different question, and its answers are only useful if you know that the original expression *is* undefined.  The answers there are more along the lines of why C has the concept of undefined behavior at all.  So when I see people asking about UB, I always try to slip in a quick answer or at least a comment, to give the OP some actual help before he's overwhelmed by the wall of text at the "exact duplicate" of his question.)

I suppose this is a duplicate of [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316407/is-it-a-good-idea-to-answer-low-quality-posts) or [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276572/should-one-advise-on-off-topic-questions), and I suppose the answer will be "Yes, it really is wrong, you really shouldn't answer 'bad' posts, because it only encourages more of them".

---

I didn't mention [Should one advise on off-topic questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276572/should-one-advise-on-off-topic-questions), because I'm not talking about off-topics questions -- I'm talking about nominally on-topic questions, that have been downvoted because others believe the question is a duplicate, or the OP shouldn't have asked, but I happen to believe that the OP deserves an answer anyway.

Even more to the point: If the consensus is that a question does not deserve our attention, is it so wrong to answer it that it's right to leave comments like "please don't spend your time answering poor questions like this"?

Comment: Why did you post this if you're already aware that it's a duplicate of many other posts with a solid consensus? Ironically, I almost just posted an answer restating that consensus, but since this should be closed, I shouldn't do that.

Comment: @SamHanley Do you define "duplicate" as "off-topic"?  That, is it would have been on-topic, except that it's been asked before?

Comment: No, a question that's on-topic but a duplicate isn't off-topic, but it still should be closed, and shouldn't be answered with a fresh copy of the same answer. Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357021/reputable-people-keep-answering-duplicates-whats-the-solution and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252009/should-there-be-a-deterrent-for-answering-obvious-duplicate-questions

Comment: There's a recent discussion related to this here: ["Does the recent blog post on being less hostile contradict “How to Answer”'s advice on not answering bad questions?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366780/does-the-recent-blog-post-on-being-less-hostile-contradict-how-to-answers-adv) that might be closer to what you're asking. See also ["Is a comment telling someone not to answer constructive?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348633/is-a-comment-telling-someone-not-to-answer-constructive)

Comment: @BradLarson Thanks.  "[Is a comment telling someone not to answer constructive?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348633/is-a-comment-telling-someone-not-to-answer-constructive)" is an exact duplicate of what I'm asking about, and I'll happily accept closure on that basis.

Comment: It's fine if people disagree on whether a question is a duplicate or not. If you really think it isn't, and it's worth answering, it would be great if you could edit it to make that more clear. Maybe then other people would see what you see. But some people apply duplicate more broadly than others. It really is subjective, to some extent.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Edit what? My question here, or that hypothetical not-so-duplicate question there?  Anyway, I'm not talking specifically about dups, but more generally about questions which have been downvoted, but I disagree, and think a fresh answer is worthwhile.

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity. I did mean "that hypothetical not-so-duplicate". But I'd say the same thing whether people are thinking it's a duplicate or otherwise low quality. If you see some value and it appears that other people are missing it, an edit can definitely be helpful.

Comment: I really don't want to make it sound like I'm advocating answering bad questions, though. I'm assuming that if you're considering answering it, that you see something there that's worth answering, even if it needs a lot of cleanup for other people to see it. If that's not the case, it's best to vtc. But if it is, I'm just saying, do the cleanup if you're going to answer.

Comment: @SamHanley "Why did you post this if you're already aware...?" Because I don't see this as a solid consensus, I see this as an ongoing discussion.  (Also because I hadn't seen [Is a comment telling someone not to answer constructive?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348633/is-a-comment-telling-someone-not-to-answer-constructive), which *is* an exact duplicate.)

Comment: @SteveSummit: "*But that's actually a different question, and its answers are only useful if you know that the original expression is undefined.*" Which you will quickly find out by *reading the question* and its answers. The information the user wants is *right there*; they just have to read it, and do so with a mindset of *learning* rather than trying to match patterns to their exact code. You are basically trying to digest what that canonical Q&A is saying and regurgitate it in a form the OP will immediately understand. That does a disservice to the OP and the site.

Comment: @SteveSummit: "*So when I see people asking about UB, I always try to slip in a quick answer or at least a comment, to give the OP some actual help before he's overwhelmed by the wall of text at the "exact duplicate" of his question.*" And in so doing, you are subverting the very intent of the concept of canonical duplicate questions. Someone writing a comment letting you know that your behavior is inappropriate is entirely reasonable.

Answer (score 11):

Oh joy.  *Another* misleading comment.

To the point of the question:  it's not advised to answer bad questions, since the answer at best will be *incomplete*.  This has an adverse effect for anyone looking for answers elsewhere, and incomplete questions frequently turn into [chameleon questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43478/175248).

To the comment:  that's not valuable.  It actively detracts from any message intended to be sent.  It reads as noise and should be flagged for removal as such.  As I stated before - the only message needed was closure, and that was intended for the OP.  Sure, the answerer probably shouldn't have answered that question, but instead of commentating about it, energy should've been focused instead on getting the question closed.

To your main argument:

> ...[I] would never discourage anyone from leaving a good answer to a "bad" question.

Objectively poor questions cannot have objectively good answers.  A poor question in this context is one which is otherwise off-topic.

Comment: The quotes in the question are significant.  I am not advocating answering objectively bad questions.  By "'bad' questions" I mean questions that have been downvoted or put on hold, but where I believe a good answer serves the OP and the programming community better than the approach the donvoters are advocating (whether it's "this question is unworthy of our site" or "this question is adequately answered by this allegedly exact duplicate").

Comment: @Makoto you really shouldn't answer duplicate questions like this ;-p